# Twitter Sharing URL from personal site is not working as expected

Tags: php, html, facebook, twitter, share

I have a new website, which I've just uploaded my first blog post onto.

I have social sharing buttons on the page, but a few don't seem to work as expected.

In Twitter the URL doesn't appear at all. Its as if its ignored. Here's the twitter link:
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?url=http://www.andrewburns.info%2Fblog%2Ffirstsortedvalue+function+in+Qlikview+script.php&via=AndyBurns89

Facebook and Reddit work fine. Google plus cuts off the URL after the first space, even though i used urlencode on the link:
https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.andrewburns.info%2Fblog%2Ffirstsortedvalue+function+in+Qlikview+script.php

I tried posted the link directly into Twitter and it doesn't seem to recognise that its a webpage at all. It doesn't shorten the link down like it normally does.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent. Take a look at the query parameters and notice the `http:%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F`